# Why is the destructor getting called twice but the constructor only once?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

My code is

```
class CTemp{
public:
    CTemp(){
        printf("\nIn cons");
    }
    ~CTemp(){
        printf("\nIn dest");
    }
};

void Dowork(CTemp obj)
{
    printf("\nDo work");
}

int main()
{
    CTemp * obj = new CTemp();
    Dowork(*obj);
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I get is

```
In cons
Do work
In dest
In dest
```

Now why does the constructor get called once but the destructor is called twice? Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void Dowork(CTemp obj)
```

Here local-copy will be done, that will be destruct after exit from scope of `DoWork` function, that's why you see destructor-call.

Comment: so that means in this case the copy constructor gets called?

Comment: @singh yes. default-implemented copy c-tor will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a copy constructor and check again:

```
CTemp(const CTemp& rhs){
        printf("\nIn copy cons");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function is called its parameter is created by using the implicit copy constructor. Add to your class the following copy constructor

```
CTemp( const CTemp & ){
    printf("\nIn ccons");
}
```

to see one more message about creating an object